# $(135)(12)$ verfies the property $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I have just proved in another thread that $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$

> I tried to apply the property to the permutation $(135)(12)$, but it is not working.
>
> $((135)(12))^{-1}=(12)^{-1}(135)^{-1}$

If the number I pick as example is only in one the cycles (like 3) the proof I gave applies to that particular case. But if I pick 1, I have:

$((135)(12)(1))^{-1}=(135)^{-1}(2)=2$, however $(12)^{-1}(135)^{-1}(1)=(12)^{-1}(5)=5$

**Question:**

What did I do wrong?

Comment: $(135)(12)$ maps $5\mapsto 1$, hence its inverse should map $1\mapsto 5$, which $(12)(153)$ does indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(135)(12)$ maps $5$ to $1$, so its inverse maps $1$ to $5$ (not to $2$).

You should not start with $((135)(12)(1))^{-1}$ but with $((135)(12))^{-1}[1]$ where for clarity the argument $1$ is found between the brackets $[,]$.

Answer (score 1):

What does $((135)(12)(1))^{-1}$ mean? It should be $((135)(12))^{-1}(1)$ and that should be $5$ because $(135)(12)(5) = 1$.